# Angular ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Mn' before initialization after usging d3-org-chart?

Tags: d3.js, angular14

I am using "d3-org-chart for implementing org chart in our angular app with 14 version i have tried each and everything according to doc but after loading i got ***Cannot access 'Mn' before initialization***
i am using below version for "d3-org-chart as well as d3 i am sharing my component code snippet i am not understand what's the issue can anybody help me on that how to fix above issue.

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import   OrgChart from "d3-org-chart";  
import * as d3 from "d3";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-genealogy',
  templateUrl: './user-genealogy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-genealogy.component.scss']
})
export class UserGenealogyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("chartContainer") chartContainer: ElementRef;
  chart;
  data:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    d3.json(
      'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bumbeishvili/dc0d47bc95ef359fdc75b63cd65edaf2/raw/c33a3a1ef4ba927e3e92b81600c8c6ada345c64b/orgChart.json'
    ).then((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      this.chart = new  OrgChart();
      this.updateChart();
    });
  }

  updateChart() {
    if (!this.data) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.chart) {
      return;
    }
    this.chart
      .container(this.chartContainer.nativeElement)
      .data(this.data)
      .svgWidth(500)
      .initialZoom(0.4)
      .onNodeClick((d) => console.log(d + ' node clicked'))
      .render();
  }

}
```

```
  "d3": "5.15.1",
  "d3-org-chart": "^1.0.12",
```

sadsa